# Can the Kaltura API be used to search private videos?

Tags: kaltura

If I locate a private video in the Kaltura backend, I can take that entryId and use it in the API to embed that video on a page.

However the ASK is for me to basically make a media browser on the site itself, or at least like a video picker so admins can find and show a single video on a page without needing to go the Kaltura backend to get those Ids.

If I just query the media list itself, it's returning just 3 videos that all seem to be public... but we have a few hundred in the system.

Is it even possible?